# fighting with awk

Tags: shell, awk, reporting

Problem:

I have file like below with several figures and characters

1. field: no of time IP found (`69.175.54.106` = `17`)
2. field: IP address,
3. field: country name (`US` - America, `CN` - China  etc),

If you see below IP `69.175.54.106` was resolved 283 times but not for 17 so I want to sum of first field with matched second filed and third field should be there as country name

```
17, 69.175.54.106,
283, 69.175.54.106, US
77, 58.77.59.10, CN
23, 58.77.59.10,
```

**Output should look like:**

```
300, 69.175.54.106, US
100, 58.77.59.10, CN
```

Comment: Try to use a language like python to solve this kind of problem

Comment: No, awk is a perfect solution for these kind of jobs.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this might work for you:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=", *"}
{sum[$2]+=$1 }
! country[$2] && $3 != "" {country[$2] = $3}
END { for ( k in sum ) { print sum[k] ", " k ", " country[k] } }' INPUTFILE
```

[See it in action at Ideone.com](http://ideone.com/HbZNEA).

Line by line

1. in the `BEGIN` block set up the field separator (to get rid of the unwanted spaces)
2. for every line add the time to an array indexed by the IP
3. if the country code wasn't stored yet, and the 3rd file is not empty, store it in another array (indexed by the IP)
4. finally for every IP print the sum, IP, and country code

Comment: you can remove the `! country[$2] &&` part.

Comment: It depends. What if the country code was already saved and is a different one?

Comment: one IP resolved to two different countries? ;) and even in that case.. why would you prefer the first entry?

Comment: Láttál-e már karón varjút :-) (stupid hungarian joke about impossible things happening). I prefer the first one, because it was npt specified otherwise.